# Turning a text file into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, file-io

I'm trying to write a function that takes text file as input and turns it into the JSON tree format below so I can use it in my d3.js project.

The text file is really simple: Every line that starts with 'b' represents a bag and the following integer is the number of the bag. Each bag contains nodes.

So the first line is bag 1 with the nodes 1 and 2.
The lines that does not contain b represent the links between the bags. So bag 1 points to bag 2 for example.

Sample input:

```
b 1 1 2 3
b 2 2 3 4
b 3 4 5 6
1 2
1 3
```

Expected output:

```
const tree = {
  id: 1,
  name: '1, 2, 3',
  vertices: [1, 2, 3],
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: '2, 3, 4',
      vertices: [2, 3, 4],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: '4, 5, 6',
      vertices: [4, 5, 6],
    },
  ],
};
```

code so far (help from tom):

```
function readTreeInput(evt) {
  const file = evt.target.files[0];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function convertTreeToJSON() {
    const lines = this.result.split('\n');
    const res = {}; let current = res;

    for (let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
      const textLine = lines[line];
      if (textLine.startsWith('c') || textLine.startsWith('s')) continue;

      if (textLine.startsWith('b')) {
        const bagId = parseInt(textLine[2], 10);
        const firstNode = textLine[4];
        const secondNode = textLine[6];
        const thirdNode = textLine[8];
        let vertices;

        if (secondNode === undefined) {
          vertices = [firstNode];
        } else if (thirdNode === undefined) {
          vertices = [parseInt(firstNode, 10), parseInt(secondNode, 10)];
        } else {
          vertices = [firstNode, secondNode, thirdNode];
        }
        current.id = bagId;
        current.name = vertices.join(', '); // bagLabel;
        current.vertices = vertices;
        current = (current.children = [{}])[0];
      }
    }
    removeExistingTree();
    drawTree(res);
  };
  fileReader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Not quite sure how to go from here to take care of the nesting, any advice? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any problem there ? ;-) I prefer easier textLine.split(' ') but left most of your code untouched. And suppose FileReader would not work here.

```js
var result = document.createElement('PRE');
result.innerText = x = JSON.stringify(
    convertTreeToJSON.call({ result: 'b 1 1 2\nb 2 2 3\nb 3 4 3\nb 4 5 4\n1 2\n2 3\n3 4' })
    , null, 1)
    .replace(/\[\n\s+(\d+),\n\s+(\d+)\n\s+]/g, '[$1, $2]')
    .replace(/\[\n\s+/g, '[').replace(/}\n\s+\]/g, '}]');
document.body.appendChild(result);
function convertTreeToJSON (x) {
    const lines = this.result.split('\n');
    const edges = [];
    const treeBags = [];
    const listOfIds = [];

    var res = {}; var current;

    for (let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
        const textLine = lines[line];

        if (textLine.startsWith('c') || textLine.startsWith('s')) return;

        if (textLine.startsWith('b')) {
            const bagId = parseInt(textLine[2]);
            let bagLabel;
            let vertices;
            const firstNode = textLine[4];
            const secondNode = textLine[6];
            const thirdNode = textLine[8];

            if (secondNode === undefined) {
                vertices = [firstNode];
            } else if (thirdNode === undefined) {
                vertices = [parseInt(firstNode), parseInt(secondNode)];
            } else {
                vertices = [firstNode, secondNode, thirdNode];
            }

            if (res.id === undefined) {
                current = res;
            } else {
                current = res.children[res.children.push({}) - 1];
            }
            current.id = bagId;
            current.name = vertices.join(', '); // bagLabel;
            current.vertices = vertices;
            if (current == res) current.children = [];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I would want to change is if a node has no children I want it to be like in the output above: no line or array so it would just be  id: 4, name: '5, 4',vertices: [5, 4] is there a way to do this?

Comment: No worries get some sleep, thanks for the help :) The lines in the text file that don't start with b determines the links between the nodes. So bag 1 is linked to bag 2 and bag 1 is also linked to bag 3, so the tree would look like this: https://imgur.com/wEXc7HX aka the first node in this case would have 2 children

Comment: You can play with again ;-)